# Define a static variable for a recursive function in OCaml

Tags: variables, recursion, ocaml

I have a recursive function `fact`, which can be called from either an expression inside it or an expression outside it.

I would like to associate `fact` with a variable `v`, such that each time `fact` is called from **outside** (another function), `v` is initialized, and its value can be changed inside `fact`, but never can be initialized when `fact` is called from **inside**.

The following code suits my need, but one problem is that `v` is defined as a global variable, and I have to do `v := init` before calling `fact` from outside, which I do not find beautiful.

```
let init = 100
let v = ref init

let rec fact (n: int) : int =
  v := !v + 1;
  if n <= 0 then 1 else n * fact (n - 1)

let rec fib (n: int) : int =
  if n <= 0 then 0 
  else if n = 1 then (v := !v + 50; 1)
  else fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

let main =
  v := init;
  print_int (fact 3);
  print_int !v; (* 104 is expected *)

  v := init;
  print_int (fib 3);
  print_int !v;; (* 200 is expected *)
```

Could anyone think of a better implementation?

Comment: While the variable `v` has a larger *scope* than the `fact` function, I wouldn't call it *static*.

Comment: @huitseeker: I guess the terminology comes from C, where if you define a local function variable as *static*, it is only initialized at first call, and the same value is reused at later call. This is quite often used to propagate internal information across function calls. (There are even languages such as early Fortrans where all function variables were static, that is the compiler had no concept of dynamic frame allocation on the stack, everything was allocated at compile-time, and in particular you could not have two calls of the same function live at the same time; no recursion.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adapt Martin's solution so that data is shared across various calls:

```
let fact =
  let counter = ref 0 in
  fun n ->
    let rec fact = ... in     
    fact n
```

The idea is to transform `let fact = fun n -> let counter = ... in ...` into `let fact = let counter = ... in fun n -> ...`: counter is initialized once, instead of at each call of `fact`.

A classical example of this style is:

```
let counter =
  let count = ref (-1) in
  fun () ->
    incr count;
    !count
```

Beware however that you may get into typing trouble if the function was meant to be polymorphic: `let foo = fun n -> ...` is always generalized into a polymorphic function, `let foo = (let x = ref ... in fun n -> ...)` is not, as that would be unsound, so `foo` won't have a polymorphic type.

You can even generalize the counter example above to a *counter factory*:

```
let make_counter () =
  let count = ref (-1) in
  fun () ->
    incr count;
    !count
```

For each call to `make_counter ()`, you get a new counter, that is a function that shares state across call, but whose state is independent from previous `make_counter ()` counter creations.

Answer (score 5):

You can hide the function and value definitions within the body of a containing function as follows:

```
open Printf

let init = 100

let fact n =
  let rec fact counter n =
    incr counter;
    if n <= 0 then 1 else n * fact counter (n - 1)
  in
  let counter = ref init in
  let result = fact counter n in
  (result, !counter)

let main () =
  let x, count = fact 3 in
  printf "%i\n" x;
  printf "counter: %i\n" count (* 104 is expected *)

let () = main ()
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment... I have one remark about your code: If the inner `fact` contains two calls of `fact` inside, the values of their `counter` are independent with each other, that is not exactly what I want : `... and its value can be changed inside fact ...`

Comment: Or `let fact n = let counter = ref init in let rec fact n = ...`

Answer (score 1):

With Ocaml's objects, you can do:

```
class type fact_counter = object ('self)
  method get : int
  method set : int -> unit
  method inc : unit
  method fact : int -> int
end;;

class myCounter init : fact_counter = object (self)
  val mutable count = init
  method get = count
  method set n = count <- n
  method inc = count <- count + 1
  method fact n =
    self#inc;
    if n <= 0 then 1 else n * self#fact (n - 1)
end;;
```

Then you can obtain:

```
# let c = new myCounter 0;;
val c : myCounter = <obj>
# c#fact 10;;              
- : int = 3628800
# c#get;;                  
- : int = 11
# c#set 42;;               
- : unit = ()
# c#fact 10;;              
- : int = 3628800
# c#get;;    
- : int = 53
```

I hope you can easily see how to adapt `myCounter` to include `fib` ...